# Why useEffect triggered before paint

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I understand that one of the distinctions between `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect` is as follows:

- useEffect triggered after paint
- useLayoutEffect triggered before paint and block the browser paint process

However, why does the following useEffect trigger before paint?

1. useEffect triggered before paint

```
performance.mark('start')
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    performance.mark('end-useEffect')
    performance.measure('useEffect triggered', 'start', 'end-useEffect');
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>123</div>
  )
}
```

[image]

2. use useEffect and useLayoutEffect together: useEffect triggered after paint

```
performance.mark('start')
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    performance.mark('end-useEffect')
    performance.measure('useEffect triggered', 'start', 'end-useEffect');
  }, [])
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    performance.mark('end-useLayoutEffect')
    performance.measure('useLayoutEffect triggered', 'start', 'end-useLayoutEffect');
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>123</div>
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Best guess: React probably only _guarantees_ that `useLayoutEffect` it will run before paint, because it probably matters if you are using that hook. And makes no guarantees for `useEffect` since it probably doesn't matter, but it may opt to run it before paint sometimes for performance reasons that we don't really have to care about. Which raises a follow up, why does it matter? Does this behavior cause you any issues?

Comment: I'm learning react internals, the above code is just to verify the triggering timing of useEffect. The execution result of the code confuses me

Answer (score 0):

I found a helpful article that dives into this topic and provides insights, you can refer this- https://thoughtspile.github.io/2021/11/15/unintentional-layout-effect/

Answer (score 0):

I found an insightful article in explaining this with exceptional detail.

https://jser.dev/2023-08-09-effects-run-paint/

Short answer:

> useEffect() callbacks are run after DOM mutation is done. Most of the
> time, they are run asynchronously after paint, but React might run
> them synchronously before paint when it is more important to show the
> latest UI(for example when re-render is caused by user interactions or
> scheduled under layout effects), or simply if React has the time
> internally to do so.